# Quick Nurikabe Puzzle: $4$s

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Nurikabe** (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/nurikabe.html))
>
> - Fill in the cells with black under the following rules.
> - You cannot fill in cells containing numbers.
> - A number tells the number of continuous (adjacently) white cells. Each area of white cells contains exactly one number in it and they are separated by black cells.
> - The black cells are linked to be a continuous (adjacently) wall.
> - Black cells cannot be linked to be 2x2 square or larger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a correct solution:

> [image]
>  
>  I'm not sure whether it makes sense to talk to the logic in great detail - I started from the bottom left corner (only one of the 4 cells in the corner can be white, and it has to be white to adhere to the "no 2x2 black blocks" rule), and then just went from there.

Comment: This is correct, well done! :D --- (oot: btw I'm a fan of your Codeforces' April Fools Contests~ XD)

Comment: @athin It's a small world :-)